# Why does QWebFrame omit a large part of my HTML?

Tags: html, qt, parsing

I have HTML in form of a `QByteArray`, and I would like to parse it.

```
QWebPage webpage;
webpage.mainFrame()->setContent(html);
QWebElementCollection elements = webpage.mainFrame()->findAllElements("div");
```

However, it turns up empty, even though the html has plenty of `<div>`s.

If I print `qDebug() << webpage.mainFrame()->toHtml();` all I see is `"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"` anthough in `html` there is a nice big page, with header, body, tables, and contents.

If I use `setHtml` instead of `setContent` by converting `html` to `QString`, I get a litte bit more, but not much. If I print `qDebug() << webpage.mainFrame()->toHtml();` I see the header with its contents but without the stylesheets, but the body is completely omitted. It ends with `"...</head></html>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large content, the DOM structure may not be available just after the calls to `setContent` or `setHtml`, you should let the event loop run and wait for the signal `QWebPage::loadFinished()` before doing anything on the DOM (and even then, if there is javascript involved, the final DOM won't be there yet).

You can use `QEventLoop` or a loop with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` to wait for the signal within the same function.
For instance:

```
QWebPage webpage;

QEventLoop loop;
// The signal is connected with Qt::QueuedConnection, 
// so that the loadFinished signal always trigger the quit() slot 
// even if the loop wasn't needed
QObject::connect(&webpage, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loop, SLOT(quit()), 
                 Qt::QueuedConnection);
webpage.mainFrame()->setContent(html);

loop.exec();

QWebElementCollection elements = webpage.mainFrame()->findAllElements("div");
```

Comment: I thought this only happens if I use `load()` to get the page from an external (web) resource. It works now if I wait for the `loadFinished` signal. It all makes sense now, originally, `setHtml` probably loaded a little bit more than `setContent ` because of the conversion from `QString`.

Comment: @vsz I modified the code: the signal was emitted, but the quit() slot was called synchronously, before exec() had time to run. By connecting the slot before the call to setContent and by using `Qt::QueuedConnection`, the call to the slot is delayed until the loop is started (because of that, I'm not sure if there is a trivial solution for both large and small contents with `processEvents`).

Comment: For a larger file size a separate thread would probably be the best solution, but this simple and elegant solution now works and is sufficient for the task at hand. Thank you for your time!